# Sudo hangs after password entry - issue with /dev/null

Tags: sudo

Ubuntu 16.04.  After playing with something new (napp-it, a ZFS gui), I'm having a problem where sudo hangs after the password prompt.  Relevant strace for sudo follows...

```
open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0666) = 8
lseek(8, 0, SEEK_END)                   = 0
umask(022)                              = 077
fcntl(8, F_SETLKW, {l_type=F_WRLCK, l_whence=SEEK_CUR, l_start=0, l_len=0}
```

If I rm /dev/null and recreate it (properly with mknod and then proper permissions) sudo runs fine.  However that only holds until a reboot, at which time sudo hangs again.

Edit... I should add that immediately on reboot the permissions on /dev/null appear correct.  ls -l /dev/null yields the following (the same as after deleting and recreating it)

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Feb  8 20:58 /dev/null
```

Comment: My stock `sudo` doesn't seem to open `/dev/null` at all. Add the output of `type -a sudo` and `sudo -l` to your post, please.

Comment: That led me to the solution.  At some point a line was added to sudoers "Defaults logfile=/dev/null".  Removing this line solved the problem.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please post it as an answer instead of editing the question. (Also, can you add the exact line that was add/removed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of sudo -l indicated that sudo logging was being directed to /dev/null.

An examination of /etc/sudoers showed the following lines.

```
## supress Console messages from sudo
Defaults logfile=/dev/null
Defaults !syslog
##
```

Not sure when (or why) these were added to the sudoers file, but commenting them out solved the problem.

Comment: If this happens on your system, it is a HUGE red flag. It basically means someone wants to run commands as root without your notice. Unless you know someone at your home/officespace did this, consider yourself hacked.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing a syslog handler, and am killing the standard syslog daemon. Apparently, at least based on this strace, my guess is the glibc `syslog()` functions seems to hang on a `sendto()` system call.

I am just always stunned when something this core to working on a system does something like this. Perhaps this by design? Just seems like a poor idea.

```
read(9, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(9)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f461335d000, 4096)            = 0
read(8, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(8)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f461335e000, 4096)            = 0
socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 8
connect(8, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 110) = 0
sendto(8, "<85>Sep 11 16:53:56 sudo:     ro"..., 92, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0
```

So - if you have this issue, check on your syslog daemon, and see if it works, and `/dev/log` exists.